# Unable to INSERT a row in a table with PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I want to insert some data into a table using PDO. I looked for some examples and I found that I need to use the functions prepare, bind and then execute, however I can not figure out in my code what I am doing wrong because it inserted nothing and I have no error in the query or php code.

```
    if($_POST){

    $account    = $_POST['account'];
    $password   = $_POST['password'];
    $phone      = $_POST['phone'];
    $email      = $_POST['email'];

    $stmt =     'INSERT INTO employer(account, password, phone, email) VALUES(:account, :password, :phone, :email)';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($stmt);

    $stmt->bindParam(':account', $account, PDO::PARAM_STR,100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password',$password, PDO::PARAM_STR,100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':phone', $phone, PDO::PARAM_STR,100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR,100);

    if ($stmt->execute(array('account'  => $account,
                             'password' => $password,
                             'phone'    => $phone,
                             'email'    =>$email
                             )
                        )
        ){
    echo "success";
    }else{
        echo "error";
    }

}
```

Comment: what does error reporting/checking saying? and why are you using bindParam and array? Here read up on the subject http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Comment: You're binding twice, either bind before the `execute` statement or send an array as a parameter, not both. You should add error handling, for example by having PDO throw exceptions when something goes wrong.

Comment: @jeroen doubting they know what exceptions are. also doubting they're reading us. also doubting they read the manual.

Comment: @jeroen I know; my grammar/spelling/crystal ball aren't clear at all, *my bad*

Comment: @jeroen would you please do the honours and put in an answer, unless you too have voted to close? or if you rather not(?)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have, without more information I'm not even sure this would solve the problem. But feel free :-)

Comment: @jeroen I am trying with the suggestion you gave to me, I deleted the double bind, still does not work. I do not know how to do error handling. I am searching for it.

Comment: @Sora Add a 4th parameter when you open your PDO connection: `array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)`

Comment: @Sora you are indeed connecting with PDO, right? and not `mysqli_`?

Comment: @jeoren you were right, no need to bind. It was my first time doing that, now I understand better. This is so basic, so I do not know if it is better to close the question or not, however I will add the answer. Thank you, and so sorry for the delay in my reply.

Answer (score 0):

Error detected by @jeroen I was binding twice. So I can bind "either bind before the execute statement or send an array as a parameter, not both"

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('
INSERT INTO employer
(account, password, phone, mail)
values (:account, :password, :phone, :mail)');

  $stmt->execute( 
            array(':account'    => $account, 
                  ':password'   => md5($password), 
                  ':phone'      => $phone,
                  ':mail'        => $email
                  )
            );

  if ($pdo->lastInsertId())
    return true;
  else
   return false;
```